# Nextjs dynamic route is rendered twice

Tags: next.js

I have a dynamic route in `pages/user/[id].jsx`
my `[id].jsx`  contains `console.log(useRouter().query.id);`
if I go to `url/user/5`
When I check console once I get undefined and then the correct id (5 in this case). What is going on here, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: This is an expect behaviour for dynamic routes, see https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12010 for details.

Comment: Thank you @juliomalves, the solutions presented in the linked issue helped a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [getInitialProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps#context-object) for this.

```js
// sample usage
// file /pages/user/[id].jsx

export default function User({id}){ 
  return <div>{id}</div>
}
    
User.getInitialProps = (appContext) => {
  return {id: appContext.query.id}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the content of your page, but if you don't have `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` (or old `getInitialProps`) then NextJS handles your page as the static page and does the automatic static optimization (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization#how-it-works)

In there you can read that:

> During prerendering, the router's query object will be empty since we do not have query information to provide during this phase. After hydration, Next.js will trigger an update to your application to provide the route parameters in the query object.

To overcome the double render, you can do:

```
// pages/user/[id].jsx

import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const UserPage = () => {
    const { query, isReady } = useRouter()

    // wait until there is a query with the data; or `!query.id`
    if (!isReady) {
        return null;
    }

    return query.id;
}

export default UserPage;
```

Or if you have some useEffect:

```
// pages/user/[id].jsx

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const UserPage = () => {
    const { query, isReady } = useRouter()
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isReady) {
            // fetch(`your.domain/user/${query.id}`)...;
        }
    }, [isReady])

    if (!isReady) {
        return null;
    }

    return query.id;
}

export default UserPage;
```